# Как объединить два фрагмента кода в один?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как правильно объединить одинаковые два фрагмента кода в один?

Отличием является лишь `.blur` и `.each` в начале кода.

```
$('input').each(function(){
$(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('focused');
});

$('input').blur(function(){
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  if ( inputValue == "" ) {
    $(this).removeClass('filled');
    $(this).parents('.form-group').removeClass('focused');  
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('filled');
  }
});

$('input').focus(function(){
  $(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('focused');
});

$('input').blur(function(){
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  if ( inputValue == "" ) {
    $(this).removeClass('filled');
    $(this).parents('.form-group').removeClass('focused');  
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('filled');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$('input').blur(function() {
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  if (inputValue == "") {
    $(this).removeClass('filled');
    $(this).parents('.form-group').removeClass('focused');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('filled');
  }
}).blur();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```